# Cannot open text editor with double click in ftp Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, ftp, text-editor

I am working on some ftp in which there are some php files, but whenever I double click on files it gets opened in browser, while local php files opens in text editor. How to open php in ftp  with text editor.

Comment: same problem for me (since ubuntu 17.10), have you found a solution?

Comment: Not yet still searching for it.

Comment: Same issue here. For now I'm using the built in browser in Gedit to navigate to the files instead of Nautilus on 17.10 (in 16.04 double clicking in Nautilus still opens the remote files directly).

In Gedit hit F9 to toggle display of the sidebar. With it open browse your remote server just like in Gedit. Double clicking PHP files opens them as expected. Hit F9 again to hide the sidebar while you work.

Answer (score 3):

This is affecting 18.04 as well. The only remotely related bug (and really old one) I have found is  [Files & Folders - Favorites opens FTP in browser instead of Nautilus](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/769082) . But this proposed solution doesn't help.

> Open
>
> **/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache**
>
> Find
>
> **x-scheme-handler/ftp=firefox.desktop;**
>
> change it to:
>
> **x-scheme-handler/ftp=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;**

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a bug that needs to be looked at. I have now reported this at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1791283

Please log in there and give any feedback in comments to get this looked at.

Answer (score 2):

Open `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`, eg with vim

```
sudo vim /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

Find the line with

```
 x-scheme-handler/ftp=firefox.desktop;
```

and comment or delete it.